# what methods are there to classify documents?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, tf-idf, feature-selection

I am trying to do document classification. But I am really confused between feature selections and tf-idf. Are they the same or two different ways of doing classification?

Hope somebody can tell me? I am not really sure that my question will make sense to you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are confusion a lot of things.

- Feature selection is the abstract term for *choosing* features (0 or 1). Stopword removal can be seen as feature selection.
- TF is *one* method of *extracting* features from text: counting words.
- IDF is *one* method of assigning weights to features.

Neither of them is classification... they are *popular* for text classification, but they are even more popular for information retrieval, which is not classification...

However, many classifiers work on numeric data, so the common process is to 1. Extract features (e.g.: TF) 2. Select features (e.g. remove stopwords) 3. Weight features (e.g. IDF) 4. Train a classifier on the resulting numerical vectors. 5. Predict the classes of new/unlabeled documents.

Comment: What is the common process?
Do you mean removing stopwords is also a feature selection?

Comment: When you remove stopwords they won't become features afterwards... so yes, it is a simple form of feature selection: the word "the" is removed from your features. The common process is given in my reply (1., 2., 3., 4., 5.)

Comment: What if I use nueral network for document classificstion, how does input data look? I kind of understand the form of input data with structured data, but with tf-idf document model, I want to feel how tf-idf document model is used for input to nueral network.

Comment: Most methods work with anything that you can squeeze into numerical format. So do neural networks: they expect number arrays, matrixes or tensors, and output the same. It's up to you to find a meaningful numerical representation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/text-classification-and-naive-bayes-1.html) explanation may help a lot when it comes to understanding text classifiers.

TF-IDF is a good way to find a document that answers a given query, but it does not necessarily assigns documents with classes.

Examples that may be helpful:

1) You have a bunch of documents with subjects ranging from politics, economics, computer science and the arts. The documents belonging to each subject are separated into the appropriate directories for each subject (you have a labeled dataset). Now, you received a new document whose subject you do not know. In which directory should it be stored? A classifier can answer this question from the documents that are already labeled.

2) Now, you received a query regarding computer science. For instance, you received the query "Good methods for finding textual similarity". Which document in the directory of computer science can provide the best response to that query? TF-IDF would be a good approach to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you are classifying documents, you are trying to make a decision about whether a document is a member of a particular class (like, say, 'about birds' or 'not about birds').

Classifiers predict the value of the class given a set of features.  A good set of features will be highly *discriminative* - they will tell you a lot about whether the document is of one class or another.

Tf-idf (term frequency inverse document frequency) is a particular feature that seems to be discriminative for document classification tasks.  There are others, like word counts (tf or term frequency) or whether a regexp matches the text or what have you.

Feature selection is the task of selecting good (discriminative) features.  Tfidf is probably a good feature to select.